# Polymer paper-dialog animation is not working good in Internet Explorer

Tags: angularjs, polymer, polymer-1.0

I declare this 
`var dialog = document.getElementById('createOrUpdateModal');
        if (dialog) {
            dialog.animationConfig = {
                'entry': {
                    name: 'transform-animation',
                    node: dialog,
                    transformFrom: 'translateY(100%)',
                    transformTo: 'translateY(0)'
                },
                'exit': {
                    name: 'transform-animation',
                    node: dialog,
                    transformFrom: 'translateY(0)',
                    transformTo: 'translateY(100%)'
                }
            };
            dialog.open();
        }`.

In Chrome, is perfect but when Go to IE11 something really lagging and the dialog suddenly appear ....
Can change transform-animation to slide-down-animation/slide-up-animation to get a little bit better but still lag.

Comment: IE doesn't fully support WebComponents.

Comment: Can you provide me some reference source talk about this problem??? Omg..... Can workaround or something?????.... :'(
btw... Thanks for your help